# Android Emulator - generate intent / simulate barcode scanner

Tags: android, emulation, barcode-scanner, device-emulation

Is it possible to configure the emulator to raise a specified broadcast intent?

I'm using physical devices which have a button enabled barcode scanner.  Data is then received by the application via a broadcast intent.

I have simulated this by raising an intent using Command Prompt which is received by the app as expected.

If possible I would like to trigger for an intent to be raised from within the emulator itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have the emulator itself send Android Intents.  You could have an application on the emulator which sends Intents for you but most people I have spoken to who do this use adb commands over a command prompt, like you say.

Comment: "most people I have spoken to" is hearsay and not an answer.